# How to make «express + request» and display the data?

Tags: node.js, express, request

How to make the body site to display?

I understand that I may not pass a function variable **res**, but I do not understand how it can pass there, please show once, so that later I knew how to do it.

```
var request = require('request');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    request({
        url: 'http://google.com/'
    }, gotData);
});

app.listen(3000);

function gotData(err, res, body) {
    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); // fine
        res.send(body); // error
    }
    else {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "error"?

Comment: @mscdex TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'send'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res` you are using is not the express `res`. The `res` you want is out of scope.

```
var request = require('request');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){    // express res
  request({
    url: 'http://google.com/'
  }, function(err, res2, body) {    // request res
    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
      return res.send(body);
    } else {
      return res.send('Could not load google.com');
    }   
  }); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: And if I need to still do some action with the body and then to display, if I can be displayed in a different function? `function display(body) { // edit body and send to display }`

Comment: Sure, just add a function to make changes to the body before you do `return res.send(body);`. I'd have the function return the changes rather than passing `res` in the function.